# Node.js : Socket.io 0.9.17 - Bandwidth usage

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io, bandwidth

I'm using Node.js (v0.10.29) with Socket.io (v0.9.17). I can't upgrade Socket.io to v1.0.6 because I need to communicate with Android devices, and at the moment it seems that no one of the solutions to do it have been updated to work with Socket.io v1.0.

The problem I have is that, when using Socket.io v0.9.17, the bandwidth used is very high. As an example, for the same amount of data, Socket.io v0.9.17 uses 800KB, when Socket.io v1.0.6 uses 8KB...

Does any one knows why ? And what can I do to avoid that ?

Thanks

Comment: "ko" is a Kilo Octet (kilobyte), right?

Comment: Ooops yes, I corrected my question thanks !